# Rails views double quotes/single quotes not enough

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, quotes, double-quotes

```
<%= render 'shared/modal',
    id: 'assignToModal', 
    button: '<button onclick="groupAssignTo('<%= _id %>');">Assign</button>' %>
```

Consider the above code in a rails app view file(.html.erb). It will throw a,

```
ActionView::Template::Error (/home/think/../app/views/junks/_abc.html.erb:39: 
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
```

Its because in the button local of the render statement, the single quote starts **before <** and does not end **after >**, instead ends **before <%=**

How to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are placing `<%= %>` tag inside another `<%= %>` tag

```
<%= render 'shared/modal',
    id: 'assignToModal', 
    button: '<button onclick="groupAssignTo(' + _id + ');">Assign</button>' %>
```

Comment: Hahaha, thanks for the code review!. Stupid guy is @beck03076

Comment: Actually this worked right, button: "<button onclick=groupAssignTo('#{_id}');>Assign</button>" (note the single quote before and after _id

Comment: @beck03076 matter of taste. plus signs variant is more readable for me

Comment: You dont get it. The javascript function that im calling onclick, takes a string as an argument, whose values should be wrapped in quotes. With + there wont be quotes but with '#{}', there will be.